# Balance paid prior to arrival to hotel

Tags: single-word-requests, british-english

I am looking for adjective (if exists) for paying for hotel stay prior to arrival or if possible word that would describe paying upon checking-out ?

If there is no such word, then is there any neat expression for this type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Prepaid](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prepay#English) would probably fit your needs.

**Verb**

> 1. prepay (third-person singular simple present prepays, present participle prepaying, simple past prepaid, past participle prepayed)
>
> --To pay in advance, or beforehand; as, to prepay postage.

Answer (score 1):

*Deposit* is a payment made in advance, to secure a reservation, or as surety against (e.g.) damage or default.

The *Balance* would be paid to settle the final amount owing (for example on checking out).

Comment: A deposit would imply a payment of less than the full amount.  *Pre-paid* would imply payment of the full amount up front.

Comment: @Jim, I slightly misread the question,  taking into account the request for both advance payment and paying on checking out. So *Prepaid* as in the other answer fits properly.